# How to implement `serde::Serialize` for a boxed trait object?

Tags: rust, polymorphism, serde

I ran into a problem trying to create a generic vector for a struct.
This was my first attempt:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Card {
    sections: Vec<Section<dyn WidgetTrait>>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Section<T: WidgetTrait> {
    header: String,
    widgets: Vec<T>
}
```

This has brought me to an error that `Sized` is not implemented and `WidgetTrait` size is not known at compile time.

My next attempt was to use `Box<dyn WidgetTrait>` like so:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Section {
    header: String,
    widgets: Vec<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5bfbabe19bc6860b747d79974441e6a1&version=stable)

This has led me to an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `WidgetTrait: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 | #[derive(Serialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `WidgetTrait`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn WidgetTrait>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>`
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
```

My goal is for the widgets vector in `Section` struct to be able to accept different types of widgets that implement `WidgetTrait` trait, just like you would with an interface.

Comment: Please, can you provide a [mcve]? Ideally, your code could be copy/pasted into the playground and compile or give the expected error.

Comment: Using generics as you have in the `Section` struct will not allow you to store different Widgets which implement `WidgetTrait`, because Rust [*monomorphises*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189604/what-is-monomorphisation-with-context-to-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) generics during compilation. Just FYI, the boxed trait is generally good way to go, or an `Rc`, depending on your use case

Comment: Added playground link

Comment: You will need to implement `Serialize` manually for `Section`. Even if every `WidgetTrait` type implements `Serialize`, that doesn't mean that the type `WidgeTrait` itself does. In fact there's no way to automatically implement that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting somewhere. Added another playground link, how do I write an implementation for Box?

Comment: Did you check the [official documentation](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html)? Did you try to implement `Serialize` for `Box`?

Comment: Yes I did check the documentation, the problem is that I can't figure out a way to find out what type of `struct` comes from the `Box<WidgetTrait>` to be able to use the strongly typed `serializer`

Comment: Your latest edit does not solve your Problem, it's a complete different approach.

Comment: Tim, my problem was finding a solution on how to implement Serialize trait for Box<of Trait> which is what the solution does. Not saying it's elegant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For serializing Serde trait objects you should use [**`erased-serde`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/erased-serde).

```
// [dependencies]
// erased-serde = "0.3"
// serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
// serde_json = "1"

use erased_serde::serialize_trait_object;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Card {
    sections: Vec<Section>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Section {
    header: String,
    widgets: Vec<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Image {
    image_url: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct KeyValue {
    top_label: String,
    content: String,
}

trait WidgetTrait: erased_serde::Serialize {}
impl WidgetTrait for Image {}
impl WidgetTrait for KeyValue {}

serialize_trait_object!(WidgetTrait);

fn main() {
    let card = Card {
        sections: vec![
            Section {
                header: "text".to_owned(),
                widgets: vec![
                    Box::new(Image {
                        image_url: "img".to_owned(),
                    }),
                    Box::new(KeyValue {
                        top_label: "text".to_owned(),
                        content: "text".to_owned(),
                    }),
                ],
            },
        ],
    };

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&card).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: For the folks that feel that this is not working, special attention to the `serialize_trait_object!(WidgetTrait);`. It makes all the difference.

Comment: See my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76886066/55246) if you also want to deserialize.

Answer (score 3):

I got around the compiler errors:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;

use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeStruct};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Card {
    sections: Vec<Section>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Section {
    header: String,
    widgets: Vec<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Image {
    #[serde(rename = "imageUrl")]
    image_url: String
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct KeyValue {
    #[serde(rename = "topLabel")]
    top_label: String,

    content: String
}

trait WidgetTrait {}

impl Serialize for WidgetTrait {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer {
            let s = serializer.serialize_struct("???", 3)?;

            s.end()
        }
}

impl WidgetTrait for Image {}
impl WidgetTrait for KeyValue {}

fn main() {
    // let test = ResponseMessage { 
    //         text: None, 
    //         cards: Some(
    //             vec![Card { sections: vec![
    //                 Section { header: format!("text"), widgets: vec![ 
    //                     Box::new(Image { image_url: format!("img") }) 
    //                     ]},
    //                 Section { header: format!("text"), widgets: vec![
    //                      Box::new(KeyValue { top_label: format!("text"), content: format!("text") }),
    //                      Box::new(KeyValue { top_label: format!("text"), content: format!("text") })
    //                      ]}
    //                 ]}])
    //         }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e045d09f612d62370b4010156b40d243&version=stable)

---

Steps for a working solution.

1. Write `as_any()` implementations for your structs that implement `WidgetTrait` as per [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-struct-reference-from-a-boxed-trait).
2. Add implementation for trait `Serialize` of type `Box<dyn WidgetTrait>`
3. Downcast `Box<Widget>` to the struct so we know the type using `as_any()` and `downcast_ref()`
4. Use [documentation](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html) on how to serialize a strongly typed struct

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate serde;

use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeStruct};
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Card {
    sections: Vec<Section>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Section {
    header: String,
    widgets: Vec<Box<dyn WidgetTrait>>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Image {
    #[serde(rename = "imageUrl")]
    image_url: String
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct KeyValue {
    #[serde(rename = "topLabel")]
    top_label: String,

    content: String
}

trait WidgetTrait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any;
}

impl Serialize for Box<dyn WidgetTrait> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> 
        where S: Serializer {
            return match self.as_any().downcast_ref::<Image>() {
                Some(img) => {
                        let mut widget_serializer = serializer.serialize_struct("Image", 1)?;
                        widget_serializer.serialize_field("imageUrl", &img.image_url)?;

                        widget_serializer.end()  
                    },
                None => {
                    let key_value: &KeyValue = match self.as_any().downcast_ref::<KeyValue>() {
                        Some(k) => k,
                        None => panic!("Unknown type!")
                    };

                    let mut widget_serializer = serializer.serialize_struct("KeyValue", 2)?;
                    widget_serializer.serialize_field("topLabel", &key_value.top_label)?;
                    widget_serializer.serialize_field("content", &key_value.content)?;

                    widget_serializer.end()  
                }
            };                
        }
}

impl WidgetTrait for Image {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

impl WidgetTrait for KeyValue {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let test = ResponseMessage { 
    //         text: None, 
    //         cards: Some(
    //             vec![Card { sections: vec![
    //                 Section { header: format!("text"), widgets: vec![ 
    //                     Box::new(Image { image_url: format!("img") }) 
    //                     ]},
    //                 Section { header: format!("text"), widgets: vec![
    //                      Box::new(KeyValue { top_label: format!("text"), content: format!("text") }),
    //                      Box::new(KeyValue { top_label: format!("text"), content: format!("text") })
    //                      ]}
    //                 ]}])
    //         }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=02f427145774908a0d806e7b23e5cc0d&version=stable)

Answer (score 3):

`erased-serde` won't work if you also want to deserialize:

https://github.com/dtolnay/erased-serde/issues/25#issuecomment-605387945

The solution is to use:

https://github.com/dtolnay/typetag

All you need is `#[typetag::serde(tag = "type")]` on the trait, and `#[typetag::serde]` on the impl's.