# storing dynamic traits in a hashmap, and calling functions with its respective structure

Tags: rust

In my rust project, I'm trying to make a db like implementation that can store the state of a user from different integrations that all implement same functions through a trait, and can be written to a file later using serde with this code:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct State {
  pub current: HashMap<Bytes, Box<dyn UserState>>
  pub changes: HashMap<u64, Vec<UserStateChange>>
}
pub trait UserState {
  fn id(&self) -> Bytes;
  fn apply_change(&mut self, change: UserStateChange);
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub enum UserStateChange {
  Foo(FooChange),
  Bar(BarChange)
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct FooState {
  id: Bytes,
  count: u64,
  start: u64
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct FooChange {
  count_delta: i64
}
impl UserState for FooState {
  fn id(&self) -> Bytes {self.id.clone()}
  fb apply_change(&mut self, change: UserStateChange) {
    let UserStateChange::Foo(change) = change;
    todo!();
  }
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct BarState {
  id: Bytes,
  attempts: u64
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct BarChange {
  attempt_delta: i64
}
impl UserState for BarState {
  fn id(&self) -> Bytes {self.id.clone()}
  fb apply_change(&mut self, change: UserStateChange) {
    let UserStateChange::Bar(change) = change;
    // apply logic
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that it can store and serialize the dynamic trait, while ensuring that it supports the `apply_change` function, and can use its own structure for storing changes with relevant fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement \`serde::Serialize\` for a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021897/how-to-implement-serdeserialize-for-a-boxed-trait-object)

Comment: Also all those questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+serde+trait+object.