# Serialize complicated data structure

Tags: rust, struct, serde

I'm having trouble serializing the following struct. I have narrowed it down to, that the problem lies within the variable `objects`, containing trait structs within a HashMap. I'll try to explain my circumstances:

I have the following main struct, which i'm interested in obtaining data from:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct System { 
    pub objects: HashMap<(u32, u32), Box<dyn CommonObjects>>,
    pub paths: Vec<Path>,
    pub loops: Vec<Loop>,
    pub physics: Physics,

    pub run_limit_loops: u32,
    pub run_limit_paths: u32,
    pub error_tol_loops: f64,
    pub error_tol_paths: f64,

    pub unknown_flow_outlets: u32,
    pub unknown_pumps_id: u32,
    pub system: u32,
}
```

The kind of structs which are contained within `objects` are as the following:

```
pub struct Outlet {

    // Variables found in all structs contained within 'objects'
    pub Q: f64,
    pub hL: f64,
    pub ob: u32,
    pub id: u32,
    pub active: bool,
    pub system: u32,
    pub con_Q: HashMap<u32, f64>,

    // Variables found only in this struct.        
    pub p_dyn: f64,
    pub flow_specified: String,
    pub submerged: bool,
}

pub struct Pipe {
    // Variables found in all structs contained within 'objects'        
    pub Q: f64,
    pub hL: f64,
    pub ob: u32,
    pub id: u32,
    pub active: bool,
    pub system: u32,
    pub con_Q: HashMap<u32, f64>,

    // Variables found only in this struct.    
    pub Re: f64,
    pub f: f64,
}
```

These struct has some variables which are only used within themselves, and some variables which are common for all structs contained within `objects` (`p_dyn` is only used within `Outlet`, while `Q` is used for all structs contained within `objects`) To get these variables, get-function are defined, both within the local struct, and by the trait `CommonObject`. All i am interested in, is serializing `objects` in order to get all the variables in a string format, both the common ones, and the ones only appearing locally within a struct, so that i can send the variables to other programs to further visualization.

In this following code the error occurs:

```
// Where the system struct originates from.
let systems: Vec<System> = system_analyse::analyse_system(data); 

// I try to only serialize the objects contained within one of the system structs.
let jsonstringresult = serde_json::to_string(&systems[0].objects);

match jsonstringresult {
  Ok(v) => {
    println!("{:?}", &v);
    v
  },
  Err(e) => {
    // The error message originates from here.
    println!("An error occured at serializing: {}", e);
    String::new()
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occured at serializing: key must be a string
```

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021897/how-to-implement-serdeserialize-for-a-boxed-trait-object) discussing the issue of serializing dynamic traits, and i've followed the instructions and added the following to the trait:

```
pub trait CommonObjects: erased_serde::Serialize {
    ...
}
serialize_trait_object!(CommonObjects);
```

Which makes the code compile in the first place. I've also found [this site](https://www.greyblake.com/blog/when-serde-json-to-string-fails/) getting the same error, but the issue there seems to be with enums. Maybe the problem in this site is related to my problem, but i cant figure out how if so.

I'm open to all sort of feedback and even fundamentally change the structure of the code if so necessary.

Comment: The specific error you're getting isn't about the dynamic objects, it's because the keys of your `HashMap` are tuples (specifically `(u32, u32)`) but JSON can only have string keys (e.g. `String` or `&str`).

Comment: Oh my, i’ve completely missed the actual problem, haha! Now i could go continue searching for a solution, but if you have an solution to my problem, then i’ll greatly apprechiate an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to serialize a `HashMap` with non-string keys to Json is to use the [`serde_as` macro](https://docs.rs/serde_with/2.0.1/serde_with/attr.serde_as.html) from the [`serde_with` crate](https://crates.io/crates/serde_with/).

```
use serde_with::serde_as;

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct System { 
    #[serde_as(as = "Vec<(_, _)>")]
    pub objects: HashMap<(u32, u32), Box<dyn CommonObjects>>,
    //...
}
```

The `#[serde_as(as = "Vec<(_, _)>")]` encodes the map as a sequence of tuples, representing pairs of keys and values. In Json, this will become an array of 2-element arrays.

Comment: Uuh, looks promising, first thing tomorrow!

Comment: I've tried implementing the additional code you have supplied above, but it still gives the same error; 'key must be a string'. Do you have any thoughs of why this error still would show up?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The additional code is added to the main struct 'System', and therefore the new "rules" apply only to System, and not 'objects' alone in 'System'. Therefore, serializing 'systems[0].objects' does not work, but serializing 'systems[0]' and 'systems' works, which also is my intention, so thank you alot!