# Rust - object-safety rules are unclear - serde dyn serialize and deserialize

Tags: rust, deserialization, traits, serde

I'm attempting to do dynamic dispatch on a trait which allows for both serialization and de-serialization.
Specifically:

```rust
// [dependencies]
// erased-serde = "0.3.31"
// serde = { version= "1.0.193", features=["derive"] }

pub trait PersistentComponent: erased_serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned {}
fn main() {
    let persistent: Vec<Box<dyn PersistentComponent>> = Vec::new(); // compilation failure
}
```

The compilation fails with:

```
for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically;  
for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

The link provided in the compiler error mentions that there are certain qualities that must be followed for a trait to be object safe. However, from the list I don't know which quality are being violated here; I don't understand why it won't compile.

### Research

On stackoverflow, [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50021897/15534181) was asked but ONLY for serialization, hence my use of erased_serde. However, erased_serde does not do de-serialization.

This limitation of erased_serde was mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/dtolnay/erased-serde/issues/60), where a user is trying to solve the same problem as this post.

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021897/how-to-implement-serdeserialize-for-a-boxed-trait-object/76886066#76886066) handles deserialization.

Comment: @Jmb I took a look, and I can't get this to work (the answer does not given an example). Can you please provide a minimal example? And can you re-open this question please?

Comment: The docs for `typetag` do give an [example](https://github.com/dtolnay/typetag#example)…