# Why do I get a "match arms have incompatible types" error in a function returning `impl Trait`?

Tags: rust

```
trait Counter {
    fn count(&self) -> i32;
}

struct AddCounter {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
impl Counter for AddCounter {
    fn count(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a + self.b
    }
}

struct MulCounter {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
impl Counter for MulCounter {
    fn count(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a * self.b
    }
}

fn get_counter(a: i32, b: i32, op: &str) -> impl Counter {
    match op {
        "+" => AddCounter { a, b },
        "*" => MulCounter { a, b },
        _ => panic!(format!("{}{}", "未知的符号：", op)),
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I get an error when I call `get_counter(...)`:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 | /     match op {
27 | |         "+" => AddCounter { a, b },
28 | |         "*" => MulCounter { a, b },
   | |                ------------------- match arm with an incompatible type
29 | |         _ => panic!(format!("{}{}", "未知的符号：", op)),
30 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected struct `AddCounter`, found struct `MulCounter`
   |
   = note: expected type `AddCounter`
              found type `MulCounter`
```

Comment: [How do I return an instance of a trait from a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661046/how-do-i-return-an-instance-of-a-trait-from-a-method)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the `impl Trait` notation as a generic type. You cannot write:

```
fn get_counter<T>(a: i32, b: i32, op: &str) -> T {
    match op {
        "+" => AddCounter { a, b },
        "*" => MulCounter { a, b },
        _ => panic!(format!("{}{}", "未知的符号：", op)),
    }
}
```

because `AddCounter` and `MulCounter` do not have the same type: what is `T`?

You can use dynamic dispatch instead of static dispatch:

```
fn get_counter(a: i32, b: i32, op: &str) -> Box<dyn Counter> {
    match op {
        "+" => Box::new(AddCounter { a, b }),
        "*" => Box::new(MulCounter { a, b }),
        _ => panic!(format!("{}{}", "未知的符号：", op)),
    }
}
```

#### Further explanation

When you use static dispatch, the Rust compiler *monomorphizes* the code: it generates a new function for each value of the generic type (see [What is monomorphisation with context to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189604/what-is-monomorphisation-with-context-to-c) for more details). Each of those returned values are "real" plain types. In this case, a function cannot return (for example) a `String` in one path and an `i32` in another path.

In the case of [dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#trait-objects-perform-dynamic-dispatch), it is not the "real" type that is returned but a **trait object**: the compiler does not know the real type; it only cares that the trait object can be used as a trait implementor. That is what you need here.

Comment: `impl Trait` is not equivalent to a generic parameter (it is an unnamed output type), and the compiler doesn't monomorphize it.

Comment: `impl Trait` is monomorphized: it is static and not dynamic. If you do not want monomorphization, use `dyn` instead.

Comment: Monomrphization is not about static vs. dynamic: it is the process in which the compiler duplicates generic functions for different types. Return position `impl Trait` does not do this, because it is a single type.