# Rust won't let me return an instance of a type from a match, keeps thinking I'm trying to return a value

Tags: rust

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30661354/3536548) to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30661046/3536548) I need to do the following to return an instance of a `Trait`:

```rust
trait Shader {}

struct MyShader;
impl Shader for MyShader {}

struct GraphicsContext;

impl GraphicsContext {
    fn create_shader(&self) -> impl Shader {
        let shader = MyShader;
        shader
    }
}
```

but when I try to do it:

```rust
pub trait Component { }

struct Kind {}

struct Location {}

impl Component for Kind {}

impl Component for Location {}

pub fn get(comp_name: &String) -> impl Component {
    match comp_name.as_ref() {
        "kind"      => Kind,
        "location"  => Location
    }
}
```

I just get errors:

> error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `Kind`
>    --> src/main.rs:17:24
>
> ```rust
>    |
> 17 |         "kind"      => Kind,
>    |                        ^^^^ did you mean `Kind { /* fields */ }`?
> ```
>
> error[E0423]: expected value, found struct `Location`
>    --> src/main.rs:18:24
>
> ```rust
>    |
> 18 |         "location"  => Location
>    |                        ^^^^^^^^ did you mean `Location { /* fields */ >}`?
> ```

Comment: I think if you declared your empty (unit) structs as `struct Kind;` then you can instantiate them with no braces: `Kind`. But if you declare with braces like `struct Kind { }` then you need to have braces when you make an instance: `Kind{}`.

Comment: You have a simple typo error then you have a big problem see duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/51543177/7076153.

Comment: So there's no way to return just the type if you are using a type with fields/braces?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "return the type"?

Comment: The phrase "return an instance of a Trait" (which comes from the author of a different question) is also very misleading.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I disagree, It means I want to return the type that implements the specified trait, if I were speaking about rails, the trait would be the class `ActiveRecord` and the instances would be the models that implement the class. And "return the type" would return the type object, the struct, the thing that implements the trait, using rails again, it would be the model class itself.

Comment: I'm confused now. Do you want to return an *instance of a type* implementing`Component`, or do you want to return *the type itself* that implements `Component`? Types are a static analysis feature in Rust; they don't exist at runtime, so you can't do the latter, period. The former question is answered by the question Stargateur linked, once you fix the syntax errors.

Comment: @Thermatix My understanding is that you are trying to return runtime representations of the types themsevles, which do not exist in Rust, in contrast to other statically typed languages such as Java, C# or Go. Assuming that Rust _did_ have runtime type representations, what would you want to do with them? If you can explain your use case, I am sure we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `impl Component` as the return type is basically a `T where T: Component`, where the `T` is chosen by the function itself rather than by the caller.

`T` can be `Kind`, `T` can be `Location`, but `T` can't be both at once.

Two solutions:

1. Dynamically: Return a `Box<dyn Component>` and return `Box::new(Kind{})` or `Box::new(Location{})`. The disadvantage is that it causes an heap allocation.
2. Statically, by returning an `enum`:

```rust
enum KindOrLocation {
    Kind(Kind),
    Location(Location),
}
```

To make this usable as a `Component`, you can implement `Deref<Target = dyn Component>`:

```rust
impl Deref for KindOrLocation {
    type Target = dyn Component + 'static;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            KindOrLocation::Kind(x) => x,
            KindOrLocation::Location(x) => x,
        }
    }
}
```

The disadvantage here is that you have to write this boilerplate code.

---

By the way:

- If you define a struct with `{}` like `struct Kind {}`, you create an object of it by writing `Kind{}`, not just `Kind`.
- You need to handle the `_` case in your match: `_ => panic!()` or something.
- Don't take a `&String`, but take a `&str` instead. Then it works for *both* `&String` and `&str`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has to know how much room to reserve on the stack at compile time. As the linked answer mentions, if the concrete return type is conditional, the amount of space that would be needed cannot be known until runtime. That's what this bit of the answer is referring to:

> It does have limitations, such as [...] it cannot be used when the concrete return type is
>   conditional. In those cases, you need to use the trait object answer
>   below.

You should use the second form of the function shown in that answer if you want to conditionally return either a `Kind` or a `Location`. In that case, the `Kind` or the `Location` will be created on the heap instead of the stack; the stack will contain a `Box` that owns that heap reference, and `Box` is a type whose size is known at compile time.

Comment: I see. how do I deal with the fact that types I want to return posses a type field when I won't know beforehand what type the field may possess, only that it will possess a type of one of  a list of n types

Comment: There are different ways you might handle it. Whenever I find myself considering adding a `"type"` field to a struct in Rust, I stop and think really hard about whether the thing I'm working with should be an `enum` instead. Not a hard and fast rule, but consider that avenue as well.

Comment: The type field is used to store the type of the data that will be stored in the component, `Bool`, `String`, `Integer`, etc