# Respond with either a Redirect or a NamedFile in actix-web

Tags: if-statement, rust, actix-web

I have a small backend app written in `Rust` using `actix-web`. I want to have a function similar to the following.

```rust
async fn function(var: bool) -> impl Responder {
    if var {
        Redirect::to("link")
    } else {
        NamedFile::open_async("/file").await
    }
}
```

I get the error `` :`if` and `else` have incompatible types  expected `Redirect`, found future ``.

I think this can probably be done by reading the file into a string and using `HttpResponse`. But since `NamedFile` implements `Responder`, is it possible to make it work in this setting?

If I get rid of the if-else, each of these are valid return types, but the return types of an if-else statement must match. So, is it possible to maybe not use the if-else in this situation?

Edit: The linked solution doesn't work in this case. Changing the impl Responder to `Box<dyn Responder>` causes the trait bounds to fail. I get the following error message:

```
the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<(dyn actix_web::Responder + 'static)>: actix_web::Responder` is not satisfied
```

Maybe it can be fixed, but I don't have enough experience with Rust generics to do it.

Comment: The other question is about `match`, but it applies just the same to `if`.

Comment: For future closers: I've opened this question since the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543209/7884305 does not contain a solution that works here, and _any_ question about returning multiple types with `impl Trait` _cannot_ contain all solutions that work here (converting to `HttpResponse`). (And it also has a wrong explanation, but that is an unrelated problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic dispatch cannot work with `Responder`, but there are two other solutions.

The first is using [`Either`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/enum.Either.html), that also implements `Responder` by forwarding to the active variant:

```rust
use actix_web::Either;

async fn function(var: bool) -> impl Responder {
    if var {
        Either::Left(Redirect::to("link"))
    } else {
        Either::Right(NamedFile::open_async("/file").await)
    }
}
```

A second option, as you said, is to convert them to `HttpResponse`. They have different body types, so we also need to convert the bodies:

```rust
async fn function(var: bool, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    if var {
        Redirect::to("link")
            .respond_to(&request)
            .map_into_boxed_body()
    } else {
        NamedFile::open_async("/file")
            .await
            .respond_to(&request)
            .map_into_boxed_body()
    }
}
```

`HttpRequest` is an extractor, so you can just have this parameter in your handler function.

Comment: Thanks, the `Either` enum is very handy!