# Why do I get a size error when using a type alias of `dyn Trait`?

Tags: rust, size, type-alias

This function compiles:

```
fn edit<S: AsRef<str>>(w: S) {}
```

If I typealias the generic params:

```
type Word = dyn AsRef<str>;

fn edit(w: Word) {}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::convert::AsRef<str> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
3 | fn edit(w: Word) {}
  |         ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::convert::AsRef<str> + 'static)`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All functions need to know the size of their arguments at compile time. However, you are using `w` whose size cannot be determined at compile time. Instead to be able to perform dynamic dispatch, you need to use a trait object. You can accomplish this in 2 ways.

You can pass a pointer by using a `Box`:

```
fn edit(w: Box<Word>)
```

or a reference:

```
fn edit(w: &Word)
```

---

Another option you have is to avoid the use of trait objects altogether. You can instead make `edit` a generic method as follows:

```
fn edit(w: impl AsRef<str>)
```

or

```
fn edit<W: AsRef<str>>(w: W)
```

With this approach, the compiler performs what is known as "monomorphization" where it determines at compile time exactly which types are being passed in for your generic arguments and generates multiple non-generic versions for each of those calls with those specific types. Monomorphization is explained quite well in [What is monomorphisation with context to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189604/what-is-monomorphisation-with-context-to-c).

Comment: great explanation, thanks! To clarify, in the last code snippet, how does the compiler know the size of `w`? All it knows is that it implements `AsRef<str>`

Comment: *`w` which is a trait object* — it is **not** a trait object, which is the problem. [What makes something a “trait object”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)

Comment: *[monomorphization] allows the compiler to know the size of the arguments at each invocation site* — not really, as you can still [pass the unsized `dyn Trait` as a generic argument](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=816dee7731a50bbe6382ec56b914d6bd)

Comment: I made a wrong assumption. I've removed that part. Thank you for all the pointers

Comment: Good explaination. Yet it seems worth mentioning that you can opt out of sizing for Generic parameters: `fn edit<T: ?Sized>(t: &T)`.

Comment: @MarkusKlein in which context do you mean? i'm not sure i follow

Comment: @sshashank124 Now that I think about it again, I feel I just confused size of arguments, with size of generic parameters. Your answer is fine as is, sorry.