# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T' , Why this error?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, frontend, typescript-generics

```js
function add<T>(a: T, b: T):T {
    return a+b;
}
```

> this above code is giving error, Why?

```js
function greet<T extends number>(a: T, b: T): number {
    return (a + b);
}
```

But this above code is correct, while practicing generics I got an error

Comment: Do you understand why `{} + {}` or `null + null` or `true + true` is an error in TypeScript? If so, then the reason `add` is an error is because `T` can be anything at all, including things like `{}` or `null` or `true`.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

In the first code snippet, the error Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T' occurs because TypeScript dont know if the type T supports the + operator.

The type T could be any type, including types for which the + operator is not defined, such as objects or any other too.

TypeScript cannot guarantee that the + operation is valid for all possible types that T might represent. Hence, it raises a compilation error.

The second code snippet works because you've added a constraint using extends number.

I hope you got your answer. This is how typescript behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You might expect the first code-snippet to work, because in C++ something like this is legal:

```cpp
template <class T>
T add(T a, T b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

But in C++, this is a function template, meaning that several functions get compiled from it as you need them. If you use the function with a type that does not have the `+`-operator, say `add(boolean, boolean)`, it will try to instantiate the template and fail your compilation.<sup>1</sup>

In Typescript however, there is only one function produced from your generic, which would look like that:

```js
function add(a, b){
    return a+b;
}
```

The only purpose of the generics is to compile-time-check if you put any illegal arguments into this one single function.
Obviously this function would fail *at runtime* if the arguments don't support `+`. So typescript only allows you to use the `+`-operator when you have specified the type of your arguments as something that has the `+`-operator.
Your `add`-function restricts the arguments such that both arguments must have the same type, banning something like `add(2, true)` but allowing something like `add(true, true)` , while your `greet`-function would ban the latter, too, because `true` is not an instance of a number.

These are the two basic principles by which a language may supply generics: by recompiling or by compiling once and restricting access. C++, Rust, D use the recompile-approach, known as [monomorphization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189604/what-is-monomorphisation-with-context-to-c). Typescript, Java, and python use the latter approach of compiling a single polymorphic function and restricting its usage. Go uses an interesting [hybrid approach](https://planetscale.com/blog/generics-can-make-your-go-code-slower).

<sup>1) That is not strictly true when there are multiple `add`-templates, in that case the compiler would look if other `add`-templates are suitable, following [sfinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)</sup>